# CoreBluetooth set central delegate to another view controller

Tags: swift, viewcontroller, core-bluetooth, delegation, cbcentralmanager

I have just started translating my app to Swift, I want the CBCentralManager.delegate to be set to another view controller(One that navigation controller pushes onto).

I am trying to do the same with following code:

```
let viewCont = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("mainView")
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewCont, animated: true)
manager.delegate = viewCont
```

The variable manager is an instance of CBCentralManager and setting delegate to viewCont raises following error:

```
"Cannot assign value of type 'UIViewController' to type 'CBCentralManagerDelegate?'"
```

The declaration for the view Controller:

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController, CBCentralManagerDelegate
```

How can I solve the same?

Comment: Why do you need that? If you want that delegate methods to be called in your another viewcontroller, then declare CBCentralManager and initialise there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to downcast the view controller you receive from `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier`.  Without the downcast, all the compiler knows is that you have a `UIViewController`

```
let viewCont = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("mainView") as! MainViewController
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewCont, animated: true)
manager.delegate = viewCont
```

Once you have the downcast using `as!` then the compiler knows that it has a `MainViewController` and since this class is also a `CBCentralManagerDelegate` it is happy.